Deriving the Lagrangian In a general case
The title might lead to a different interpretation than what I what to ask. I will write what I have so far in the hope of solving this possible misunderstanding.
Assume that we have a function $\vec{f}$ that acts on a body that is constrained such that the function has to be split
$$\vec{f} = \vec{F} + \vec{R}$$
where $\vec{R}$ is the component of the force $\vec{f}$ that is normal to the constraint. This implies that another force will be applied on the body in order to compensate for the $\vec{R}$ component, such that only $\vec{F}$ remains.
Now, following an approach similar to what I read in Classical Mechanics by Goldstein, I can compute the work done by the force $\vec{f}$ which leads to
$$\vec{f} \delta \vec{r} = \vec{F} \delta \vec{r}$$
since the only possible work that appears is due to $\vec{F}$, not $\vec{R}$ because of the constraint. Next I can rewrite this result as follows
$$\vec f\cdot \delta \vec r = m \frac{d^2\vec r}{dt^2}\cdot \delta \vec r = \vec{F} \delta \vec{r}$$
$$\left(\vec f - m \frac{d^2\vec r}{dt^2}\right) \cdot \delta \vec r = 0.$$
Based on results from Newton's mechanics, I can use for the kinetic energy $E_c$ that
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial E_c}{\partial \dot{\vec r}} \right)= m \ddot{\vec r}$$
and for a conservative field given by a potential $V$ that
$$\vec F = -\nabla V = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial \vec r}$$
which leads to
$$\left(-\frac{\partial V}{\partial \vec{r}} - \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial E_c}{\partial \dot{\vec r}} \right)\right) \cdot \delta \vec r = 0.$$
At this point an observation is made that both
$$\frac{\partial E_c}{ \partial \vec r} = 0$$
and
$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial \dot{\vec r}}=0$$
such that we can introduce these terms in order to get the common expression of the Lagrangian in the Euler-Lagrange equation
$$\left(\frac{\partial E_c}{ \partial \vec r}-\frac{\partial V}{\partial \vec r} - \left(\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial E_c}{\partial \dot{\vec r}} - \frac{\partial V}{\partial \dot{\vec r}}\right)\right)\right) \cdot \delta \vec r = 0$$
or with the notation $L = E_c - V$
$$\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \vec r} - \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\vec r}}\right)\right) \cdot \delta \vec{r} = 0.$$
My question based on this approach is that if I don't know what kinds of forces I have in the system (electromagnetic, friction, something else entirely), and if I want to follow the same procedure, is it common practice to just write the force as a sum of each individual type of forces and continue with this procedure in order to get the Lagrangian?
The question arises from the common way of presenting analytical mechanics, namely that we don't know why it works but it does. I'm not comfortable with this approach from a learning perspective. I would like to have a well defined procedure that starts from some well established results (Newton's mechanics, Maxwell's equations, etc.) and get to the Lagrangian in a way that does not involve some reversed logic methods such that if I take the Lagrangian like this, then I'll get to the correct result.
I'm assuming some books or materials exist on this, but so far Goldstein is the closest I ever got to a procedure. Is this approach what is actually used?
For clarity, the procedure would be:

Write the forces that interact with the object.
Take only the components that are tangent to the constraint.
Derive something similar to $\left(-\frac{\partial V}{\partial \vec{r}} - \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial E_c}{\partial \dot{\vec r}} \right)\right) \cdot \delta \vec r = 0$ from the above derivation.
Based on the type of the forces, do some math in order to generate the same function in both main derivatives.
If successful, that same function is the Lagrangian.

Final notes:

I don't what to use the minimization approach. In that instance I have no idea what the Lagrangian is supposed to mean physically. I get that it is a function that once minimized it should give me the equations of motion for the particle, but that does not explain how I choose it for a particular case. The minimization should follow from the procedure I gave above, and it does.
I want to assume that I don't already know how some terms for the Lagrangian should look like. Assume that I am clueless of what I have to get in terms of the Lagrangian, but I do know where I should get once I solve the Euler-Lagrange equation(s).
No virtual work or virtual displacement. The derivation above uses work that takes place due to the fact that the object moves with respect to the constraint.


You are totally barking up the wrong tree.
The route you are taking is tolerable as a first introduction to Lagrangian mechanics, but is utterly the wrong direction to take in the usual uses of the scheme.
Historically, it was that the Calculus of Variations derived the Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations in general, and then it was realised that Newton's 2nd Law (N2L) could be recast in the form of EL equations, and for that, to work, it is sensible to pick the Lagrangian to be kinetic energy minus potential energy $L=T-V$ for agreement with N2L.
The next steps is that you are supposed to just write down $L=T-V$ in any nice coördinates, and differentiate twice (substituting into EL equations), and obtain the correct equations of motion. I mean, you know the coördinate system you are putting in, so you can always express the kinetic energy $T$ in your coördinate system, and you can write down the potential energy $V$ as a function of your coördinates, and so the EL equations give you a cheap and quick way to obtain the correct equations of motion without having to be quite smart in doing things that Newtonian forces way.
Not to mention that the Lagrangian method vastly handsomely rewards smart choices of coördinates and capturing the essential physics far better than Newtonian choices of coördinates would simplify derivations.
And then when it comes time to deal with a) electrodynamics, and b) simple dissipation models, you can just use the standard library of trickery that people had built up. There is no need to think extra hard, because people had already sorted out the phenomena for you.
That should suffice for goal (2) of yours.

I have no idea what the Lagrangian is supposed to mean physically.

It is the integrand making up the action; and the action appears prominently in quantum theory. Some people will say that it is kinetic energy minus potential energy, and that is perfectly sufficient physical meaning / motivation as that. Yet others will say that it does not need a physical meaning as it is.

No virtual work or virtual displacement.

There is no need for that in the usual mathematical derivation of EL equations either.
